# Sync Eclipse workspace, different OS, how?

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, workspace

I would like to sync Eclipse workspaces between XP and Seven because I often write on netbook when I'm away, on notebook at home. I used Dropbox before, because my two computers were both Seven. Now, with XP on netbook, I've got path incompatibility with extern libraries and other references. What is the best way to share my projects? 
Requirements:

1. My code shouldn't be public (no git, svn, etc)
2. It shouldn't be a payment service
3. No USB
4. I would like to maintain src + metadata in the same folder, so I don't have to change everytime nothing when I create a new project

Comment: How come `SVN` is public while `Dropbox` is not?

Comment: Use svn. It does not do anything public if you install it on your own machine.

Comment: You can use same workspace path and libraries layout on both machines. Plus you **definitely should** use version control.

Comment: I do not quite understand why an answer without the actual solution to the problem got accepted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share your projects with a Team Provider, CVS, SVN, Git, etc.  If you must use external libraries, put them in projects as well (you really shouldn't rely on anything being installed on the local machine--it's too unpredictable and as you've found not portable).  Set your JRE using an Execution Environment.  Use Classpath Variables if you must.  Don't try and keep the entire workspace identical across machines--it's flat out not supported and you'll only have yourself to blame if/when you start seeing odd and otherwise unexplainable problems.  If you're absolutely dead set on using DropBox, as with proper team providers, do it only at the project level.  Don't store the entire workspace in it.

Comment: Do you know a good SVN repository? My code shouldn't be public!

Comment: If it's like CVS, just make your own.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, but *I* don't understand what you mean.  Subversion lets you make your own repository and serve it from a machine of your own, presumably as easy as it is with CVS.  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.creating and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth .

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). It allowes you to create free Git or Mercurial repositories for your personal projects. It comes with some other handy features as well such as Wiki or issue tracking. Highly recommended.